# Bad Request when running yii2 console action

Tags: yii2, console-application, bad-request

Our app run a console action from the front-end to start sending a marketing campaign, this was working for a couple of years.

Suddenly we started getting a bad request when running that console action.
Some updates took place on our Linux server that might have something to do with this change in the app behavior.

We redirect the output for that action to a text file, in this file we see these lines:

```
    Status: 400 Bad Request
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
            ....
            ....
```

Here is the CampaignController:

```
class CampaignController {

    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $this->startSending($id, 1);
        die('only start sending, no more....');
    }

    private function startSending($campaign_id, $test = 0) {
        $siteUrl = \Yii::$app->urlManager->hostInfo . \Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl;

        $php = PHP_BINARY;

        $appDir = \Yii::getAlias('@app');
        $i = strrpos($appDir, 'frontend');
        $yiiDir = substr($appDir, 0, $i - 1);
        $outputFile = $yiiDir . "/console_output/send-campaign-$campaign_id-$test.html";

        $cmd = "php $yiiDir/yii send-campaign/send $campaign_id $siteUrl $test";

        $isWindwos = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? true : false;

        if ($isWindwos) {
            pclose(popen("start /b $cmd > $outputFile", 'r'));
        } else {
            pclose(popen("$cmd  &>$outputFile &", 'r'));
            //exec($cmd . " &>$outputFile &");
        }
    }

}
```

So what could be the reason for this bad request?
Could it be some PHP configuration got changed after server updates?

Comment: Did you try to look into the logs?

Comment: yes I looked into the logs but really could not find anything helpful

Comment: `400 Bad Request` is a very general error, it's hard to say what is the reason of it. You do not have any logs, you didn't show any code, it is rather unlikely that someone will be able to help you based on such limited information.

Comment: You are right, I edited my question to add the related code.

Comment: when I test this locally on my windows dev machine, it works well, but on the server it seems it redirects at some point, and that redirection causes this bad request error

Comment: are you using unix / ubuntu on local env

Comment: my local env is Windows 7 64bit

Comment: make sure its not case-sensitivity issue for the path

Comment: what code you posed so far is clearly working without issues, because you have content in the output files. you need to also post `actionSend` that's mapped to "yii send-campaign/send" (that's the action that outputs page content)

Comment: Before submitting this question I tried many modifications on the code. Even if I made that console `actionSend` a very simple function with just a return or echo statement I would get the same bad request error. I know it is confusing but really it is the case.

Comment: Also if I copy the command `php path-to-yii/yii send-campaign/send` and execute it manually in the server console it works, so I confirm the console action is OK.

Comment: Accidentally I made a syntax error in the `startSending` function of the `CampaignController`, I saw the php error regarding this in the output file that set for the console action, seems that the server response got redirected to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out what was wrong. Thanks for all who tried to help.

The problem was that the **PHP 5 Handler** on the server was set to suPHP.
Setting it to FastCGI solved the issue.

Anyone know why?